# Chart.js tooltip values display in two lines

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using chart.js. I want to show on hover two values in tooltip. Both of them in new line, but i really dont know how. This example still return string in one line. I tried es6 syntax with `` but without any success. Is there any way to archive that without using custom html?

```
tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
        label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
            var someValue = "dasdasd";
            var someValue2 = "dasdasda2";
            return someValue + "/n" + someValue2;
        },
    }
},
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use new-line *(`\n`)* character or ES6 syntax for that matter *(as canvas/chart.js doesn't support it)*.

Instead, you should use the [**`afterLabel`**](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks) callback function of tooltips, which returns a text to render after an individual label.

**Example**

```js
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
   type: 'line',
   data: {
      labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May'],
      datasets: [{
         label: 'LINE',
         data: [3, 1, 4, 2, 5],
         backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.2)',
         borderColor: 'rgba(0, 119, 290, 0.6)'
      }]
   },
   options: {
      tooltips: {
         callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
               var someValue = "Hello";
               return someValue;
            },
            afterLabel: function(tooltipItem, data) {
               var someValue2 = "Mindfuc";
               return someValue2;
            }
         }
      }
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me. Just simply return an array of strings as labels in tooltips callbacks.

```
 tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        let label = "Line 1";
        let label2 = "Line 2";
        return [label, label2];
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: your trick works pretty well!

Answer (score 0):

there are also other options how to split two lines in chart js tooltips:

1. By default, values are separated if provided in an array ([source](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/3512)), so in your case you could try:

   ```
   return [someValue, someValue2];
   ```
2. Or alternatively, you can use `split` ([source](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/issues/4087)):

   ```
   return (someValue + "/n" + someValue2).split('\n');
   ```

Both options should provide same result.